# system() returns -1, errno=10 when logged into Oracle

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

After an `EXEC SQL CONNECT user/pass;` command, `system("")` returns a -1 with errno=10.

We've migrated this program from Oracle 10g on HP-UX to Oracle 11g on Red Hat Linux.  This was not happening on HP-UX / Oracle 10g.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef char vc2[10];
typedef char vc4[20];

EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca;

char *oracleid = "user/pass";
char msg[400];
char env[20][200];
#define DEBUG 1
int  status = 1;


int main( argc, argv )
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    int        load_stat;

    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

    EXEC SQL TYPE vc2 is STRING(11) REFERENCE;

    vc2        load_date;

    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

        load_stat = system("");
sprintf(msg,"Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);
sprintf(msg, "status: %d\n ",load_stat);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);

sprintf(msg, "ORACLE Logon ID is %s\n",oracleid);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);

    EXEC SQL CONNECT :oracleid;

fprintf(stderr,"Connected to Oracle\n");
        load_stat = system("");
sprintf(msg,"Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);
sprintf(msg, "status 2: %d \n",load_stat);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);

    EXEC SQL COMMIT RELEASE;

fprintf(stderr,"released Oracle\n");
        load_stat = system("");
sprintf(msg,"Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);
sprintf(msg, "status 3: %d \n",load_stat);
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",msg);

exit(0);
}
```

The above code returns the following:

> Value of errno: 0
>
> status: 0
>
> Oracle Login ID is user/pass
>
> Connected to Oracle
>
> Value of errno: 10
>
> status 2: -1
>
> released Oracle
>
> Value of errno: 10
>
> status 3: -1

Comment: Have you checked what the error code `10` could mean? Have you tried to print out the error message using e.g. [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror)?

Comment: Oh and by the way, for almost *all* functions, the value of `errno` is *undefined* unless the previous function explicitly failed. Unless documented otherwise, you should never check the value of `errno` without checking that the function failed, but then you should check `errno` *immediately* (before calling any other function that could cause `errno` to be modified).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Oracle being awful. They've installed a `SIGCHLD` handler that reaps any child process that exits, breaking any use of child processes in the application. You can probably fix it by calling `signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_DFL)` after connecting to uninstall their nonsense.

Comment: This makes sense.  For context, error number 10 on RHEL (and I guess GLIBC in general) is `ECHILD`. That suggests there was no child process for the `wait()` performed by `system()` to collect -- or at least it doesn't expect to be able to collect one -- even though `system()` wouldn't try to wait at all if it had not successfully forked a child.

Comment: @John Bollinger:  Thanks for your help when I couldn't properly identify the problem!